# I cant redirect to other domain without change url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

im trying to redirect my subfolder to other domain and i want that work without changing the url

the code about htaccess inside /folder is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://domain2.com/$1 [P]
```

this redirect to the second domain but the url changed..
could it be a conflict with the htacces in the root?
root htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

# Remove ".php" from urls
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

# Redirect to https version
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =""
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

#indexies
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex home.php
```

im new with htaccess but it all seems correct..

Comment: Do you have control over `domain2.com`? What you are trying to do here is configure a "reverse proxy" - this is not a "redirect" as such. However, to configure the "reverse proxy" properly requires access to the server config to prevent any redirects from `domain2.com` redirecting the request back to `domain2.com` (away from the source domain).

Comment: @MrWhite no, i dont have control over domain2.. i can do something more with vhost on my domain? or what else can i do? atm im trying to do this with iframe but i've some problem